# My EULA is not displaying

Tags: java, android, eula

Hey there,
So I have the EULA code written up and in the application, I have the strings set the way it says to, i have it calling it in the main pages onCreate, and I have a EULA.txt written up and in the assets section. The problem is that it does not display the text. The box shows up with the title, a section where the text should be displayed, and the accept/decline buttons. I'm not exactly sure why the text wont display in it. Would appreciate any help... thanks.

Comment: Maybe you want to paste some of your code?

Comment: Something is wrong where you try to read the string resources. Please post some code if you want proper help.
Also, when you say "I have the strings set the way it says to", what is "it"?